# What is a practical way for maintaining a secret (from public) patch to a git repo?

Tags: git, github, build, config, git-submodules

I am doing a demo app for a particular platform (Jolla Sailfish) on github and it is going to have some ids/keys that I don't want public to see. For example, I definitely don't want public to see the real Mixpanel or Google Analytics keys. Public version should have them empty or use completely different keys.

That said when I build app for myself I do want my own keys to be used. So I want to get a generally public repo, with a minimal modification that is to stay private and secret.

What is a practical way to achieve it?

It should somehow be possible with the help of submodules with one of the submodules coming from my private repo (e.g. from bitbucket), but I somehow can't figure out the whole thing that would work for both public and me.

How would you do it? Or has anybody had similar situation on your own projects?

Comment: Put it in a configuration file, outside of the Git repo?  Users can modify the configuration file to put in their own Google Analytics keys.

Comment: use environment variables to store your keys. You code can fetch values from there. To do more advanced things, you can use deployment tools such as capistrano, chef or puppet. These tools can handle your usecase very well

Comment: Thing is I'd like to store my private keys in version control as well. It's ok if it is stored in another DB and I am fine with synchronizing versions on these (it's going to contain 1-2 config files only). So somehow private DB should modify a public file, replace it or at least add a file somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did in the end for https://github.com/amarchen/Wikipedia :

1. Main public git project has a submodule pointing to a private git repository. This submodule is checked into something like "settings/AppStoreKeys" directory
2. If you do not have access to the private repo, component will fail to be checked out and you won't have any files inside the subdirectory. The rest of the public repo will work just fine without any git errors or whatever. 3rd party users of your code may not even notice there is a private settings submodule unless you use some other components.
3. If you do have access to the private repo, you fetch the component via "git submodule init" and "git submodule update". That creates your private files in settings/AppStoreKeys
4. At runtime your code checks for the existence of files in settings/AppStoreKeys and reads settings from there or falls back to something default

*Downsides*
For my purposes it works just fine. It's a demo app, I just don't want people studying the code to overuse the real app mixpanel keys (and whatever other keys). I also don't care about a potential need to use the other keys - it's a demo app, not for supported forks.

However, this approach exposes the address of my private repo to everybody and that's not very cool. For the more serious cases I would probably go the other way around and created a private project that would be just a wrapper (plus private keys) for the public library and maybe a public app wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

What I did in my dotfiles is to have a 'private' branch, since I always specify which branches to push to which remotes, there's never a problem.